# Virtualmin Installation getting conflicts between attempted installs error

Tags: centos7, vps, virtualmin

Installation of Virtualmin on CentOS7 Running VPS. Getting following error when running the installation script. Removed all PHP versions also.
[image: Error Log]

**I tried following methods to resolve this issue**

1. Clearing cache
2. Removed all PHP versions via yum commands

When Try to remove "php56u", getting following error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsY7r.png)

Comment: Please share more details - is this related to programming after all? If yes, please share the code involved, the error message you are facing in text form, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.